# Resizing UItableview For Different Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints

I have a view controller with a simple scrollable table.  It has dimensions 320 x 340 and is positioned in the lower half of the display.

I want to resize it depending on which device is used.

I am using Auto Layout and set a constraint on the height with:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableHeightConstraint;
```

I don't see any fixed constraints that would affect it and I have this in my header file (which does identify the device in the simulator correctly):

```
#define isiPhone6Plus ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736)?TRUE:FALSE
```

I  have this in viewDidLoad:

```
if(isiPhone6) {
    self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = (467);
    [self.tableView needsUpdateConstraints];
    NSLog(@"Height constraint%f",self.tableHeightConstraint.constant);
}
```

NSLog shows the value is being set correctly, however the table size doesn't change. I have similar code for other devices but the table won't move.

Any thoughts welcome, I saw other suggestions at this site, mostly for cell height which didn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override **viewdidlayoutsubviews**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
  {
      [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
      self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)/2; // If your table view cover half the screen.
  }
```

When using autolayout we perform all frame related changes in this method. viewDidLayoutSubViews is called when frame is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutIfNeeded) after you update the constraints.

```
if(isiPhone6) {
    self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = (467);
    [self.tableView needsUpdateConstraints];
    NSLog(@"Height constraint%f",self.tableHeightConstraint.constant);

    [self layoutIfNeeded];         /// Add this
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though this did give me an error though whereas Irfan's solution dropped straight into my code.